# How to Access ElasticSearch Kibana Dashboard which is in Private Subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I have an elastic search in private subnet and I want to access the Kibana Dashboard which I am not able to. So any suggestion on how to do it? Should I use a proxy for it?

Comment: How about using an [SSH tunnel](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/ssh-tunneling-with-aws-private-subnet/)?

Comment: Hey, can you please guide me because I can't use VPN Tunnel for it.

Comment: You should use a reverse proxy(nginx ec2 micro instance) with ELB.

Comment: Just one thing why Elastic Load Balancer (ELB)?

Comment: I was able to access it by proxying it.